# Slow performance when refreshing after 10 mins

Tags: symfony

I don't know if this is a common issue but in my symfony2 project when I load for the first time it takes around 4 seconds (Profiler saying) after a direct refresh , it takes around 100ms.
I know that it needs to create the cache that's why it takes a long time.
But when I wait around 10 mins and refresh, it takes again around 4s to load.
Does the cache get deleted and symfony2 tries to recreate it ? 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Wait, are we talking about `dev` environment here? If we are, that's pretty much expected...

Comment: actually, no it's not the dev Env, It's the prod (I'm using app.php)
I'm just enabling the profiler in the prod env.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your setup is.

Could be the symfony cache being dropped, could be a mysql connection timing out and for some reason being slow to reconnect, could be the mysql cache being dropped.

You could lookup in the profiler where the time is used, maybe that gives you a clue.

Comment: it basically takes a long time when rendering the twig. any idea ?

Comment: How long are we talking here? Does the profiler show about 10 seconds to be used up by twig? if so, which call exactly? maybe post a sreenshot?

Comment: No ! Worst case 3 seconds, I'm using all the tips for enhancing the performance (APC, APC cacheloader etc ..)